# How do I remove function added to clicked element, when I click outside of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, horizontal-scrolling

I have a funcition that adds mousewheel horizontal scrolling to selected div.

I want to add this function to the element when I click on it, and remove it when I click outside of it. Not sure how to do it though, adding functionality works fine, but I can't figure out how to remove this function if I click outside the div (so even if mouse is within the div, horizontal scrolling won't take place).

Here's my jquery:

```
$mainDiv.on('click', function() {

    $(this).find($scrollableContainer).horizontal();

});
```

Function responsive for horizontal scroll (mousewheel plugin):

```
$.fn.horizontal = function() {  

    $(this).mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

};
```

In other words, what I'm trying to achieve is: if user clicks on `$mainDiv` - add `horizontal()` function to `$scrollableContainer`, but if user then clicks outside `$mainDiv`, remove `horizontal()` function from `$scrollableContainer`. I did try clicking on the body but that didn't work:

```
$('body').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find($scrollableContainer).off();
});
```

Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 3):

First modify the plugin

```
$.fn.horizontal = function(didgeridoo) {  

    this[didgeridoo]('mousewheel', fn);

    function fn(e, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

};
```

then to activate

```
$mainDiv.on('click', function() {

    $(this).find($scrollableContainer).horizontal('on');

});
```

and deactivate

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
    $(this).find($scrollableContainer).horizontal('off');
});
```

It is rather strange to use a variable in `find`, unless that variable holds a selector as a string ?

Note that there is no `delta` as a second argument, and that the `mousewheel` event is non-standard, and according to [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel) shouldn't be used? Are you using another plugin to provide non-standard functionality ?

There are however `deltaX` and `deltaY` properties of the event in Chrome and IE, they can be accessed like this

```
function fn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaX;
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
}
```

And [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) has a polyfill that should work cross-browser.

Comment: what does the syntax mean `this[on]`?

Comment: @thomas - `on` is just an argument passed in, so really it becomes `this['on']` or `this['off']` depending on what is passed to the function, and since bracket notation is the same as dot notation, it's the same as `this.on` or `this.off`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a particular reason you chose square-brace over dot syntax?

Comment: Would `$.fn.horizontal = function(on)...` be better written as `$.fn.horizontal = function(switch)...`? It looks like it can take either `"on"` or `"off"`.

Comment: I chose square brackets to be able to pass in a variable, and yes, `switch` would probably be a better name for the variable, except it's a reserved keyword, so it would have to be something like `swap` etc. instead.